# React showing data with nested routing (id)

Tags: reactjs

Hello everybody is there someone who knows how i can show this data because it does not work for me here. I made a custom hook to fetch data. and now i want to access all the different products that are with a specific id. for example (categories/2). In the picture you can see the hook and de product.js where im trying to display the data.

I got a error message once that I should put it in an array? But I don't understand what that means. Im getting the data from an api with an mysql database.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useFetch = (url) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null)
    const [error, setError ] = useState(null)


useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        fetch(url) //custom url so you can reuse it
        .then(res => {
            if(!res.ok) {
                throw Error('could not fetch data');
            }
            return res.json();
        })
        .then(data =>  {
            setData(data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            setError(null)
        })
    }, 1000);
}, [url]);

    return [data, error] //use properties with custom hook
}


export default useFetch;
```

```
import React from "react";
import "../Style/menu.css";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import useFetch from "../ApiService/useFetch";
import ProductList from "../Components/ProductList";

const Product = () => {

    const { id } = useParams();
    const { data: product, error } = useFetch('http://localhost:8080/products/category/' + id);

        return (
            <div>
                {error && <div>{ error } </div>}
                {product && (
                    <h1>{product.name}</h1>
                )}
            </div>
        )
}

export default Product;
```

Comment: Please use formatted code blocks instead of screenshots.

Comment: Alright I just added them

Answer (score 0):

Your custom hook is returning an array but you're attempting to deconstruct it. You need to change

```js
const { data: product, error } = useFetch('http://localhost:8080/products/category/' + id);
```

To

```js
const [product, error] = useFetch('http://localhost:8080/products/category/' + id);
```

Comment: Hey John. Then it says cannot read properties of null (reading name)

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answer and renamed data to product.

Comment: Hey John, It still doesn't display. Same error (properties of null) reading name

Comment: Have you console logged your product?